# Meteor mongo $near not sorting correctly

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoid3

I am trying to get the nearest postings in my meteor project.  It is returning my four postings, but not sorted by distance from origin.  I added these two indexes:

```
db.postings.ensureIndex({ loc : "2d" })
db.postings.ensureIndex({ loc : "2dsphere" })
```

And ran the following query:

```
Postings.find loc:
    $near:
      $geometry:
        type: "Point"
        coordinates: [ 39.107225, -84.501956 ]
```

But it returns them in this order:

```
_id:xs.. 39.239881, -84.359919 15.2 miles (according to google maps)
_id:aK.. 39.239881, -84.359919 15.2 miles
_id:8z.. 39.107225, -84.50195600000001 0 miles
_id:An.. 39.405906, -84.52211699999999 30.5 miles
```

Here is an example document:

```
{
"_id": "xsTpnpw7eCAgFS565",
"loc": [39.239881, -84.359919]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Postings.find loc:
    $near: [ 39.107225, -84.501956 ]
```

Comment: i was using the 2dsphere index and a query which passed the GeoJSON object (with type & coordinates properties), my sorting did not work. it also did not work in the mongo command line. then i changed to this style of query and a plain-old 2d index, everything worked. what gives?